# Connect to share ShareDrive with c#

Tags: c#, networking, sharepoint, share, onedrive

I want to connect with c# to a share drive.

The following code only works if entered path into the explorer before start the program (no password was needed). Then it will work till a restart the worksttion. Does anyone know how I can avoid this?

```
string _rootDirectory = @"\\mysites.inside-share.xxx.com@SSL\my\xxx\Documents\xxx\";
Directory.CreateDirectory(_rootDirectory);
```

Error Message: A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: The network path was not found.

Environment: PC which tries to connect to a company sharepoint server. The program is running by a user

Comment: Please specify your environment. Is this inside an active directory domain or a workgroup? Do you run the program below your user or is it running in background?

Answer (score 0):

```
/// <summary>
/// Accessing network share folder.
/// </summary>
public class NetUse
{
    string _sharename, _user, _password;

    public NetUse(string ShareFolder,string Username, string  Password)
    {
        _sharename = ShareFolder;
        _user = Username;
        _password = Password;
    }

    [DllImport("mpr.dll")]
    private static extern int WNetAddConnection2A(ref NetResource pstNetRes, string psPassword, string psUsername, int piFlags);
    [DllImport("mpr.dll")]
    private static extern int WNetCancelConnection2A(string psName, int piFlags, int pfForce);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct NetResource
    {
        public int iScope;
        public int iType;
        public int iDisplayType;
        public int iUsage;
        public string sLocalName;
        public string sRemoteName;
        public string sComment;
        public string sProvider;
    }

    private const int RESOURCETYPE_DISK = 0x1;

    public void Login()
    {
        string destinationDirectory =  _sharename;

        NetResource nr = new NetResource();
        nr.iScope = 2;
        nr.iType = RESOURCETYPE_DISK;
        nr.iDisplayType = 3;
        nr.iUsage = 1;
        nr.sRemoteName = destinationDirectory;
        nr.sLocalName = null;

        int flags = 0;
        int rc = WNetAddConnection2A(ref nr, _password, _user, flags);

        if (rc != 0) throw new Win32Exception(rc);
    }

    public void Logout()
    {
        string destinationDirectory = _sharename;
        int flags = 0;
        int rc = WNetCancelConnection2A(destinationDirectory, flags, Convert.ToInt32(false));
    }
}
```

usage:

```
var _NetUse = new NetUse(@"\\mysites.inside-share.xxx.com@SSL\my\xxx\Documents\xxx", "<username>", "<password>");
                    _NetUse.Login();
                    //Do the operations here
                    _NetUse.Logout();
```

Hope it helps.